# Creating paging within a page.php wordpress

Tags: php, pagination, wordpress

I am trying to create a paging within the page.php my thema and is not showing up ! How do?

I'm doing as follows:

Loop:

```
<?php
 $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
 $query_prof = array('post_type' => 'Professor', 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'paged'=>$paged);
  $profLoop = new WP_Query($query_prof);
if( $profLoop->have_posts()) : while( $profLoop->have_posts()) : $profLoop->the_post(); 
get_template_part('partials/content','professores'); ?>
<?php endwhile;  
?>
```

calling on page:

```
<?php wp_pagenavi( array( 'type' => 'Professor' ) ); ?>
```

Paging appears , no more list is the first direct

Comment: It is not at all clear what your are trying to do or what you are asking.

Comment: @RohitGupta I'm trying to make a paging within a page ( page.php )